# github api to refresh_token throws bad_refresh_token error when access_token is expired

Tags: github, access-token, github-api, refresh-token

I am trying to build a github app. I use the access token api(https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token) to get the access token for the user. I then use the same api with refresh_token to get a new access_token. The problem I see is this - As long as the access_token hasn't expired, I am able to generate a new access_token using the refresh_token. But when the access_token expires(and the refresh_token hasn't expired), I can't generate a new access_token.

I get the error as `error=bad_refresh_token&error_description=The+refresh+token+passed+is+incorrect+or+expired.&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.github.com%2Fapps%2Fmanaging-oauth-apps%2Ftroubleshooting-oauth-app-access-token-request-errors%2F%23bad-verification-code`

Comment: Did you ever figure out this problem?  I have the exact same issue.

Comment: Nope. Looks like this is still in beta and has issues. Started using non expiring tokens

Answer (score 0):

Got the details from https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/24745. 3 years have passed, and this problem still exists.